# Conditional expectation of the sum of random variables given their difference.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am trying to solve the following problem. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables, with $E(X)=E(Y)=0$, $E(X^2)=9$ and $E(Y^2)=216$. Also define $S=X+Y$ and $D=X-Y$. Compute $E(S|D)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S|D)$. The problem appears in one of Jim Pitman's final exams for his undergraduate course in probability at UC Berkeley.

Here are a few thoughts. The random variables $S$ and $D$ are jointly Gaussian but not independent. Their covariance and correlation can be computed, as follows. 
Since $E(S)=E(D)=0$, we have that

$$\operatorname{Cov}(S,D)=E(SD)-E(S)E(D)=E(X^2-Y^2)-0=E(X^2)-E(Y^2)=9-16=-7.$$

We can build the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ for $S$ and $D$ (which have zero mean),

$$
\Sigma=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
E(D^2) & E(SD) \\
E(SD) & E(S^2)
\end{array}
\right],
$$

and compute the joint density from here. At this point we can compute the conditional probability density
$$
f_{S|D}(s|d) = \frac{f_{S,D}(s,d)}{f_D(d)}
$$
where of course $f_D(d)$ is Normal$(0,25)$, and proceed from here to compute conditional variance and conditional expectation.

Do you think there is a shorter way to solve the problem?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the input! I'm new here. Anyway, I've edited the question by adding what I believe is sufficient 'context', which includes my own thoughts on the problem.